# Behavioral simulation in TCL Batch Mode

Tags: tcl, simulation, vivado

I have a behavioral simulation, which stores all needed information after simulation in a .txt file. I need to run this simulation about 8000 + times with different parameters, which are generated in MATLAB. I would like to run a TCL script with different parameters. What I have so far:

From MATLAB I call Vivado in batch mode with following parameters:

```
system('C:/Xilinx/Vivado/2015.4/bin/vivado -mode batch -nojournal -nolog -notrace -source E:/Projects/Vivado/Test_Files/VivTCLstim.txt -tclargs 256 32 15 25790');
```

The TCL script looks as follows:

```
open_project E:/Projects/Vivado/THD/THD_VHDL.xpr
set_property top tb_THD [get_filesets sim_1]
set_property top_lib xil_defaultlib [get_filesets sim_1]
set_property generic N=[lindex $argv 0] [get_filesets sim_1]
set_property generic DWIDTH=[lindex $argv 1] [get_filesets sim_1]
set_property generic ITER =[lindex $argv 2] [get_filesets sim_1]
launch_simulation
run [lindex $argv 3] ns
close_sim
```

However, it seems that Vivado does not change the values. It always runs simulation for 1000 ns (default set up) and uses generic parameters which are set by default in .vhd file. I’ve also tried to set generic parameters through GUI as shown here http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/64118.html (this is where I got the TCL commands from), but the simulation parameters don’t change. What can be the cause? And is my script and the way to do the simulation in the batch mode right or not?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run the simulation through Vivado. Vivado has command line tools for each step in a simulation:

- VHDL source file compilation => xvhcomp
- elaboration => xelab and
- simulation run => xsim

The first step can be skipped, because xelab can also trigger the compile steps. You just need to provide a *.prj file containing all needed VHDL source file.

```
vhdl mylib my/source/file1.vhdl
vhdl mylib my/source/file2.vhdl
vhdl test  my/source/testbench.vhdl
```

You can provide top-level generics to the simulation and of cause, you can provide your own Tcl file for xsim in batch mode. I wrote a Python wrapper around these tools to control all steps in the simulation run, and it works fine :).